# Matrix multiplication with numpy.einsum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following two arrays with shape:

```
    A = (d,w,l)
    B = (d,q)
```

And I want to combine these into a 3d array with shape:

```
    C = (q,w,l)
```

To be a bit more specific, in my case d (depth of the 3d array) is 2, and i'd first like to multiply all positions out of w * l in the upper layer of A (so d = 0) with the first value of B in the highest row (so d=0, q=0). For d=1 I do the same, and then sum the two so:

```
    C_{q=0,w,l} = A_{d=0,w,l}*B_{d=0,q=0} + A_{d=1,w,l}*B_{d=1,q=0}
```

I wanted to calculate C by making use of numpy.einsum. I thought of the following code:

```
    A = np.arange(100).reshape(2,10,5)

    B = np.arange(18).reshape(2,9)

    C = np.einsum('ijk,i -> mjk',A,B)
```

Where ijk refers to 2,10,5 and mjk refers to 9,10,5. However I get an error. Is there some way to perform this multiplication with numpy einsum?

Thanks

Comment: Quick question: you're missing an `m` from your subscripts string. Should it be `np.einsum('ijk,im -> mjk',A,B)`? This creates a new array - is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I do that I get the following error:
operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,10,5)->(10,5,2) (9,2)->(2,newaxis,newaxis,9)

Comment: When I run your 'I thought of the following code', but change `'ijk,i -> mjk'` to `'ijk,im -> mjk'` (as @ajcr suggested) I don't get an error.

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I put it in slightly different. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shapes `A = (d,w,l), B = (d,q), C = (q,w,l)` practically write the `einsum` expression

```
C=np.einsum('dwl,dq->qwl',A,B)
```

which I can test with

```
In [457]: np.allclose(A[0,:,:]*B[0,0]+A[1,:,:]*B[1,0],C[0,:,:])
Out[457]: True
```